# C# LDAP query to retrieve all users in an organisational unit

Tags: c#, ldap

I'm trying to run an LDAP query which will return all users which belong to the organisational units `OU=Employees` and `OU=FormerEmployees` and I am not getting anywhere.

I tried searching using the `distinguishedName` but that doesn't appear to support wildcards. I know there has to be an easier way but my searching effort hasn't yielded any results

Comment: Do you mean **organizational unit (OU)** or **group** ?? Those are quite different and behave differently....

Comment: I would recommend using something like [AD Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963907) to test your LDAP queries and if they work in this tool, put them in your code.

Comment: @marc_s The objectClass is OrganizationalUnit so I think that is the one I want.

Comment: @UweKeim I've been playing in AD Explorer, the only way I can seem to make it work is using DistinguishedGroup endswith however when you use the ends with operator it doesn't list the query string. When I attempt in the code to say something like distinguishedgroup=*OU=Employees, etc it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and newer, you can use a `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching:

```
// create your domain context and define what container to search in - here OU=Employees
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YOURDOMAIN", "OU=Employees,DC=YourCompany,DC=com");

// define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a UserPrincipal 
// that is still active
UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
qbeUser.Enabled = true;

// create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

// find all matches
foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
{
    // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....          
}
```

If you haven't already - absolutely read the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) which shows nicely how to make the best use of the new features in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`

If you prefer the "old" .NET 2.0 style, you would need to create a base `DirectoryEntry` that corresponds to your OU you want to enumerate objects in, and then you need to create a `DirectorySearcher` that searches for objects - something like this:

```
// create your "base" - the OU "FormerEmployees"
DirectoryEntry formerEmployeeOU = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=FormerEmployees,DC=YourCompany,DC=com");

// create a searcher to find objects inside this container
DirectorySearcher feSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(formerEmployeeOU);

// define a standard LDAP filter for what you search for - here "users"    
feSearcher.Filter = "(objectCategory=user)";

// define the properties you want to have returned by the searcher
feSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
feSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn");
feSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenName");
feSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");

// search and iterate over results
foreach (SearchResult sr in feSearcher.FindAll())
{
    // for each property, you need to check where it's present in sr.Properties
    if (sr.Properties["description"] != null && sr.Properties["description"].Count > 0)
    {
       string description = sr.Properties["description"][0].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. That worked a treat. I used the "old" method as that is how the existing code was written. Is there a performance advantage in using the new method, if so I may look at converting it (I'm new to LDAP routines).

Comment: @user914082: I don't think the "new" S.DS.AM has any performance benefits at runtime. It's built on top of S.DS - it's *easier* to use - so your performance (writing the code) will be better - but I don't see any runtime performance benefit...

Comment: @marc_s Can you please help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40236144/need-all-users-detail-name-email-designation-department-in-the-current-orga

Comment: @Sak: without any further information, it's impossible to help - what is the name of your **domain**?? Which **AD container** do you want to search in?? What is the problem you're having exactly - are you getting an error - if you please show it! Are you getting no data at all ? Are you getting incorrect data?? What would be the **correct** data then??? Loads of questions - without answers to these, no one will be able to help you

Comment: From what I can tell, from people who know way more about this than me - it appears the "new" method, while potentially cleaner code, hides implementation details that can actually be much slower, at least according to https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/12/15/better-performance-activedirectory.html