# "The server cannot handle directory requests" when querying trusted domain

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have a service running as NetworkService which tries to access a trusted AD server (we have tried both domain trust and forest trust), but there seems to be an issue with the AD server used. A wild guess is that I have to provide a server name and a valid user from the remote domain in the `new LdapConnection` but I cannot find how to get a valid server name and user and password from the `TrustRelationshipInformation`.

The following code is executed on a machine in `production.local`, which has a two-way trust with `test.local`:

```
using (LdapConnection Connection = new LdapConnection(""))
    SearchRequest Request = new SearchRequest("DC=test,DC=local", filter, System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchScope.Subtree, allRequiredProperties);
    ...
    SearchResponse SearchResponse = (SearchResponse)Connection.SendRequest(Request);
```

and it throws the error

> System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryOperationException:
>   The server cannot handle directory requests

Comment: What if you use PrincipalSearcher and not SearchRequest/SearchResponse: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7721756/3254405

Comment: Pass ldapdirectoryidentifier with test.local domain into ldapconnection ctor and verify that the networkservice account has sufficient privileges in test.local domain

Comment: @numbtongue I am not sure I can get Exchange AddressList objects through a PrincipalSearcher...

Comment: @oldovets That worked. If you make that an answer, I will accept it.